# Filter an array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this array object

```
var customers = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "1",
    "position": "1",
    "office": "<button data-id=2 class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-trash fa-lg'></i> Delete record</button>",
    "active": "1"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "2",
    "position": "2",
    "office": "<button data-id=2 class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-trash fa-lg'></i> Delete record</button>",
    "active": 0
}];
```

What i need is to make a new array that will only have active customers, that new array will look like

```
var activeCustomers = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "1",
    "position": "1",
    "office": "1",
    "active":"1"
}
}];
```

Because you may see there is only one active customer?

Comment: The `activeCustomers` variable you have is not valid JSON. There's an extra end-brace. Also, do you want `office` to be 1? It seems like you would want the `office` to retain the same value since you never mentioned otherwise.

Comment: This is not json, it objects in array

Comment: JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation and `activeCustomers` is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter` on the array.prototype ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))

```
var activeCustomers = customers.filter(function(customer) { return customer.active; });
```

**Note**: You'll have to use the MDN polyfill for browser support below IE9.

Comment: active: 1, id: 1name: "1"office: "<button data-id=2 class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-trash fa-lg'></i> Delete record</button>"position: "1"

Comment: It doesn not retunr prover way, now first is active?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery function [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/):

```
var activeCustomers = $.grep(customers, function(c){return c.active;});
```

Note that this will work in all browsers; the alternative approach would be to use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which is a (relatively) new addition to JavaScript and will fail in some older browsers.

Comment: Please make sure you have my latest edit (I missed off the return statement initially)

Comment: Giving answers via a 'fiddle' (or other external link) is discouraged on this site, if the link breaks the answer becomes useless. I've tested this against your array and it worked fine for me, doesn't it work for you?